# Automated Number String conversion in java constructor

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to define a class Expression, which can represent any mathematical expression as its name suggests. It takes a String and uses its information to store the expression in its fields.

So its constructor should look like this:

```
        public Expression(String expr)
        {
             SomeOperation(expr);
        }
```

When I make an instance of this class, **I want to be able give its constructor any type of variables or sequence thereof and make the constructor convert it into a String.**
For example, I want to be able to write:

```
Expression e1 = new Expression(aNumber*x + anInt*y)
```

instead of

```
Expression e1 = new Expression("" + aNumber+"*x+" + anInt+"*y+")
```

where x and y are **not** declared or initialised variables, but symbols to be converted into the String (aNumber and anInt are declared and initialised.)

So my question is: **Can I automate the process of concatenating Numbers and Strings in the constructor into an easily usable one, as shown above?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually implement it, something like:

```
public class Expression {
    private final String expr;
    public Expression(Object... args){
        this.expr = Arrays.asList(args).stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
    public String getExpr() {
        return expr;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
new Expression(aNumber, "*x + ", anInt, "*y");
```